# Multiple Rules under Rule Set

Tags: 6, rules

I am trying to create a Rule set which has 4 Rules under it. Using this Rule set as an action in a Triggered Rule. I want that when any of the these 4 Rules is True, the action is triggered.

But looks like the Rules under Rule Set is assigning them AND condition. How can I set it to OR condition.

I have tried changing the logical operator to Or for each group. But that is not working.

Am I missing something, or this feature is not a part of Drupal 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got my problem. I was using checkbox cck field. So the Rules were checking all values to be matched. To overcome this issue, I used Rules Bonus Pack module and in that used "Field value is one of several" condition.

Finally got it working as desired!